# Importar dados do Excel para SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-excel

Preciso importar os dados que estão no excel para uma tabela no sql.
Olhei em vários sites porém nada até agora deu certo.
Usando o sql server management studio fiz o seguinte até agora, seguindo o [passo a passo](http://codigofonte.uol.com.br/codigos/importando-uma-planilha-excel-no-sql-server):

```
sp_configure
'show advanced options', 1
reconfigure
sp_configure
'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1 
reconfigure
```

/* Criando a tabela com os meus atributos da planilha */

```
create table funcionario(
Código INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Nome VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
Admissão SMALLDATETIME NULL,
Departamento VARCHAR(100) NULL )
```

/* Comando para importar a planilha na tabela */

```
INSERT INTO FUNCIONARIO SELECT
* FROM OPENROWSET ('Microsoft.Jet.OleDB.4.0',
'EXCEL 8.0;Database=F:departamento.XLS'
,Dados$)
```

Tudo ocorre bem neste caso até a ultima parte, onde tenho o seguinte erro:

```
Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OleDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)".
```

Realmente não sei mais o que fazer.

Comment: Qual a versão e edição do seu sql server (Express, etc) ? Especifique melhor o que você precisa: Você quer uma rotina para importação? Ou você quer somente importar a planilha ?

Comment: @gmsantos estou usando a versão 2012, e preciso somente importar a planilha!

Answer (score 7):

Você pode usar o *SQL Server Import and Export Wizard* (incluído no SQL Server ) para fazer isso.

[image: Atalho para o SQL Server Import and Export Wizard no menu iniciar]

Com ele, é possível até criar a tabela de destino, ou utilizar uma tabela já existente.

Utilizando a versão 32 bits, escolha o provedor do Microsoft Excel para o *data source* e no destino o driver do SQL Server.

[image: Importar a partir do Excel]

[image: Exportar para o SQL Server]