# Backup banco de dados SQL SERVER

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, backup

Tenho um banco de dados armazenado no servidor do cliente.
Tenho acesso apenas a connection string desse banco de dados, logo consigo gerencia-lo, como posso fazer o backup do bd no **Servidor** para **Minha maquina Local**, para fazer testes?

Comment: Tem o SSMS (Sql Server managmente studio) na sua maquina local?

Comment: Sim, tenho o SSMS (Sql Server managmente studio)

Answer (score 0):

Se você já tem o SQL Server rodando na sua maquina local uma saída é utilizar o SQL Server Import and Export Wizard para importar as tabelas remotas para sua instancia local.

Selecione o servidor remoto como o Source e a sua maquina local como Destination. Um passo a passo detalhado pode ser [encontrado aqui<sup>en</sup>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209.aspx). Como não tenho o SQL Server instalado aqui no momento, não posso detalhar mais, porém os passos são semelhantes [as telas dessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30413/4751).