# Problema ao Migrar Banco de Dados MySQL para SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, mysql

Não estou conseguindo migrar uma banco de dados do MySQL para o SQL Server, usando Database Migration do MySQL Workbench.

Na autenticação do Servidor SQL Server, ele utiliza o login sa, já tentei redefinir a senha desse login, mas não consegui. Também tentei alterar a autenticação de, Autenticação Windows para Autenticação SQL Server e não consegui.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Faça o inverso, utilize o [Import and Export Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209.aspx) do SQL Server ou o `Integration Services`.

Comment: o código de erro é bem claro.. 01S00... indica string de conexão inválida.  Observando bem o screenshot, vc está no Source RDBMS, quer dizer, a base de dados onde estão os dados. Se quer migrar do MySQL para o SQL Server, então por quê escolheu o destino na especificação do source ? Deveria ser MySQL.. o SQL Server vc escolhe na etapa seguinte, em "Target Selection"..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O recurso de *Database Migration* do *Workbench* só funciona para **importar** de outros bancos de dados para o próprio MySQL, não o contrário.

Repare que a sessão *target* só é possível especificar uma conexão ao MySQL, e não com outros sistemas.

[image: Migration Database]

Você deve então fazer o **contrário** e utilizar o *SQL Server Import and Export Wizard*. [Essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30413/4751) mostra de forma sucinta como usar dessa ferramenta, no seu caso basta alterar o *source* para o MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Experimente usar o SSMA - SQL Server Migration Assistant

Ele pode migrar de versões do MySQL acima de 4.1 e pode entregar em SQLServer de 2012 até 2019

Você vai precisar instalar um MySQL Connector/ODBC v5.1